# setting rowID as identity (should be ascending number) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have this following sql script

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (rowID int IDENTITY, 
                         woID varchar(100), srID varchar(100), 
                         woWorkOrderNumber varchar(100), 
                         woSequenceCount varchar(100), 
                         WorkOrderNumber varchar(100)
                        )

INSERT INTO @tmpTable (woID, srID, woWorkOrderNumber, woSequenceCount, WorkOrderNumber)
   SELECT 
      woID, srID, woWorkOrderNumber, woSequenceCount, 
      SUBSTRING(woWorkOrderNumber, 11, 20 ) AS WorkOrderNumber 
   FROM 
      WorkOrder 
   WHERE
      codeSICurrentStatusCode NOT IN (3, 4) 
      AND SUBSTRING(woWorkOrderNumber, 11, 20) = ''

SELECT * FROM @tmpTable
```

But I'm getting these results on my rowID column:

[image]

As you can see, the `rowID` seems to be the row number from the table I selected on. What I'm trying to achieve on this temp table is that the `rowID` starts from 1 then 2 then 3 and so on and so forth.. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on SQL Fiddle?  Do you have any code between the `declare` and the `insert`?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't inserted any data before it?

Comment: Try adding IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor, that's default anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `ORDER BY` on the `INSERT` statement `SELECT` clause in order to control the order of identity value assignment.  You can alternatively use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of IDENTITY to ensure there are no gaps and provide complete control over the values.

Comment: I don't see how ordering the result set can affect the IDENTITY from inserting other values..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "affect the IDENTITY from inserting other values."

Comment: Well, you are saying "in order to control the order of identity value assignment". Ordering the result set before inserting it will not change to order of identity values being assigned. They will be assigned as 1,2,etc.